# Hide second click event in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, double-click

I have to hide the second click event  from  all anchor tags except the anchor tags which will enable popupfun. I have created a sample page

```
[JS Fiddle][1]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ananth3087/LgLnpvf4/15/

**Link Anchor Tag :** 
    This page contains two anchor tag (link 1, link 2) which are simple anchor tags which will redirect to particular page, In my example, I'm redirecting it to same page.

**Form Submit Anchor tag :**

Another two anchor tags ( form submit 1 , form submit 2) which will submit the form when we click that anchor tag.

**Popup Anchor tag**
Last two anchor tags ( popup 1, popup 2) will display an alert.

I'm trying to remove the second click  event or functionality for Link anchor tag and form submit anchor tag, But I don't want to remove the click functionality for Popup anchor tag.

So I'm using this script , its working fine ,except this is applying to Popup anchor tag also which it should not.

Basically, i want to avoid second click for particular anchor tag ( except Popup Anchor tag).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This issue can be easily fixed by using selector or class

Answer (score 0):

In your example your `div` around the poup buttons has the class `form_submitthree`, which seems unique. Extend your you jQuery code with the `:not` selector to exclude the buttons:

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".menu_table:not(.form_submitthree) a[disabled]",function() { 
    alert("disabled"); 
    return false; 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LgLnpvf4/13/

Comment: secelite, thanks for your reply. But i cannot use the class. I have to globally select the anchor tag using a tag and avoid selecting the popup tag..

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem can be answerable using CSS with the help of:

> pointer-events:none

Setting to none will prevents all click, state and cursor options on the specified HTML element. I tried to make a simple prototype from where you can take up as per your requirement. Here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/gr51yvaj/

```
$('a').click(function() {
if($(this)[0].textContent=='somelink1.com')
   $(this).addClass('ex');
});
```

For once, all link click will work. But after that based on requirement of which link to be disable afterwards, we can add some class on that dynamically and provide required CSS which will prevent click thereafter.

I find it a interesting problem. No clue why others had downvoted for the question.